# zeroMQ: cannot open libzmq.so.4

Tags: zeromq

I am trying to install the zeroMQ for my server(redhat 7). Here is what I did:
1) download the zeroMQ and unpack it.
2) navigate to the file where I put the zeroMQ and run the commands below:
./configure
make
make install

Now I can find two head files in /usr/local/include: zmq.h and zmq_utils.h and five files in /usr/local/lib: libzmq.a libzmq.la libzmq.so libzmq.so.4 libzmq.so.4.0.0.

Then I try to code like this:

```
#include <zmq.h>
...
void * context = zmq_init(1);
```

But I get this error message: undefined reference to `zmq_init'
I find that the include works well but it cant find 'zmq_init', so maybe it's the problem of lib files. But all of the lib files have been in /usr/local/lib, right?

What should I do?

Comment: You should tell us what you did to compile/link your program, as that's likely where the issue is. e.g. you're missing -L/usr/local/lib/ or something similar, in which there's multiple options to resolve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I got that error message because the lib files are in the directory: /usr/local/lib
What we need to do is to create a file named local-lib.conf under the directory /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and write /usr/local/lib in it. The name of the file is not important but its extension must be .conf.
Then, we must navigate to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and type this command: sudo ldconfig

Answer (score 0):

I tried the fix provided by @Yves above, but that didn't work out for me so here's another way for Debian/Git installations.

*Alternative fix:*

I have faced this issue on a Docker container which was occuring due to the libzmq/czmq which was installed by cloning the git repo.

- The problem is that the shared libraries when installed using git are located in the `/usr/local/lib` folder instead of `/usr/lib/` where usually, in my case a C/C++ program looks for shared library files.

I fixed it by copying all files from `/usr/local/lib` folder to`/usr/lib/` using the command

```bash
    $ sudo cp -R /usr/local/lib/* /usr/lib
```

- This was for a RPi/ Ubuntu-16.04 docker, the command or location of the files may vary depending on your OS.